# org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email message i18n

Tags: java, hibernate, internationalization, validation

```
@NotBlank(message = "Email is required!")
@Email(message = "Please add a correct email address!")
@Column(name = "EMAIL", unique = true, nullable = false)
private String email;
```

I'm using hibernate validation to check for valid email addresses.

How can I internationalize the validation messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the LocalValidatorFactoryBean:

```
LocalValidatorFactoryBean factory = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
factory.setValidationMessageSource( // initialize a ResourceBundleMessageSource  );
factory.afterPropertiesSet();
```

A ResourceBundleMessageSource can be used like this:

```
ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
messageSource.setBasename("messages/messages");
messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
```

For I18N files : /../src/messages/messages.properties (default) and /.../src/messages/messages_nl_BE.properties and ...

And then put your factory in the BeanValidationEventListener and register the BeanValidationEventListener

```
BeanValidationEventListener beanValidationEventListener = new BeanValidationEventListener(factory, new Properties());
HibernateConfig.register(sessionFactory, EventType.PRE_INSERT, beanValidationEventListener);
HibernateConfig.register(sessionFactory, EventType.PRE_UPDATE, beanValidationEventListener);
```

Something like this should work. (You will have to work out the details.)

---

OR in xml config :

```
<!-- The LocalValidatorFactoryBean is able to instantiate custom validators and inject autowired dependencies. -->
<bean id="validator"
  class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>

<!--
  This is the key to link Spring's injection to Hibernate event-based validation.
  Notice the first constructor argument, this is our Spring ValidatorFactory instance.
 -->
<bean id="beanValidationEventListener" class="org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener">
    <constructor-arg ref="validator"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="hibernateProperties"/>
</bean>

<bean id="mySessionFactory"   class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
...

  <!--
    A reference to our custom BeanValidationEventListener instance is pushed for all events.
    This can of course be customized if you only need a specific event to trigger validations.
   -->
  <property name="eventListeners">
      <map>
          <entry key="pre-update" value-ref="beanValidationEventListener"/>
          <entry key="pre-insert" value-ref="beanValidationEventListener"/>
          <entry key="pre-delete" value-ref="beanValidationEventListener"/>
      </map>
  </property>
</bean>
```

By default messages are retrieved from a resource bundle named "ValidationMessages". So just provide this bundle (e.g. ValidationMessages.properties) for the language(s) you need to override the default messages from Hibernate Validator (which are retrieved from the bundle "org.hibernate.validator.ValidationMessages.properties").

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#section-message-interpolation

Comment: thanks for your quick response. I'm sorry I forgot to tell, that I'm using hibernate with JPA. So the HibernateConfig cannot resolved to a type. Is there something similiar with JPA?

Comment: Well than you'll have to do it in your xml configuration files. See update in answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The second constructor argument is a properties object. But it should be a bundle right? If I use a static properties file here, for example German, it will not be possible to switch the language in the running software?